# iPhone 5 & iPhone 4 UI issues

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am making a project like Facebook menu from Github ([Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIi6y.png)). as it doesnot support for iPhone5 Screen so i recreated the project but there is some problem with the the iPhone 3.5 inch screen .
 The same is working fine on iPhone 5 screen i.e 4 inch screen.
  Please see the attached screenshots.
 Does anybody has idea whats going wrong ?.

[image]  [image]

[image]  [image]

While you can see the above screenshot,the 1st and 2nd screenshot are of iPhone 3.5 inch screen,the problem with both screen is that i am getting the green color  table view in bottom.
while the 3rd and 4th are of iPhone 4 inch screen  are have no issues.
Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: While those images are useful, they aren't very effective without some explanation of what each of them demonstrates.

Comment: in xib, g to othe autoresizing property, select all options. it may work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning Auto Layout off (if you're using Interface Builder).